# How to reduce the Skype video settings to work with an older computer

Tags: skype, cpu-usage

When making a Skype video call with a Logitech C600 webcam the video received on the other end often freezes. The local computer is has a single core AMD processor. The video being received from the other computer (Windows7 Intel T2250 @ 1.75 GHz) using the same webcam appears fine.

I suspect the issue is Skype trying to send video at higher a resolution and/or frame rate than the local processor can support.

How can I force Skype to use a lower resolution to see if that improves the video output?

There doesn't appear to be an option to adjust this under Tools > Options > Video settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you need to edit the config.xml file to edit the video settings.

1. Close Skype - Make sure you have the latest version.
2. Open "config.xml" with notepad which is found in "C:\Documents and Settings\your_windows_user_name\Application Data\Skype\your_skype_name" on Windows XP.
3. Find the  element and add the following 3 lines above and below your webcam entry

> <Video>
>        <CaptureHeight>480</CaptureHeight>
>        <CaptureWidth>640</CaptureWidth>
>   <Device>Quickcam Pro for
>   Notebooks</Device>
>        <Fps>25</Fps> </Video>

[Source](http://skypetips.internetvisitation.org/web_pages/faq.html#Q:__How_do_I_set_Skype_for_640x480_Video_Calls_for_Windows)

Comment: Downvoter - It this no longer correct? It was valid in 2010, but may no longer apply.